# How to stop direct access to Form B unless Form A is completed in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

This question applies to both **ASP.NET webforms** and **MVC apps**. I have a checkout process where there are two forms **Form A** (address page) and **Form B** (shopping cart page). The normal happy path works where the customer completes the **Form A** and then click submit button which takes him to the **Form B**.

The customer can accidently visit the **Form B** without ever visiting the **Form A** or completing the information. How can I find out whether the customer has completed the **Form A** if he access the **Form B** directly? If he has not completed the **Form A**, I want to redirect him to **Form A**. Is there a ASP.NET framework object that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only foolproof way is to save something to a database that indicates that the particular user has completed Form A. This could be actually storing some entity that is created by Form A or just some sort of log. The key is that you'll need to associate with the user, which means the "user" must actually have an account and be logged in. If it's anonymous, there won't be any real way to track them.

With this set up, then, you'd simply check in your database that the user has a record indicating they've completed Form A in the controller action for Form B. If nothing exists, you redirect the user to Form A. Otherwise, you allow them to view Form B.

And alternate approach is to use `Session` or set a cookie to indicate that Form A has been completed. There's pros and cons to both of these, and neither is foolproof. With both `Session` and a cookie you can track anonymous users, so you don't have to force a login. However, `Session` is not a permanent data store. By default, it will expire after 20 minutes of no activity, and even if you bump that timeout up significantly, it's always going to be finite.

Additionally, depending on the session store you use, it can also be very volatile. In Proc is the default, as it requires no configuration. Everything is stored in memory, but if the server restarts, App Pool recycles, etc. then all the session data is lost. It is possible to configure it to use something like SQL Server, though, and that would be very stable. Either way, you'd still have the timeout issue to deal with.

With cookies, you can set a far-future expires cookie that would effectively be permanent. However, cookies are stored client-side and can be removed by the user. They can also be manipulated (either created manually or modified). This means if a malicious user figured out how you were tracking whether Form A had been completed, they could basically fake that, and make your site think they had completed Form A, when they had actually not. Now, whether any one would care enough to do that is an entirely different matter. Still, it's something to consider.

Finally, both `Session` and cookies can effectively be disabled by the user. `Session` actually uses a cookie to store the session id, so if the user disables cookies in their browser, neither approach will then work.

Your best bet is still forcing a login and storing something in a database to indicate that Form A has been completed by that authenticated user. However, if you can deal with or mitigate the downsides of using `Session` or cookies, then those might be viable options.